# Why did this RSpec text break after changing my Rails db from SQLite to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rspec

The second example used to pass in SQLite and now fails under MySQL.

```
require 'spec_helper'

shared_examples_for "anything that caches its model" do

  factory = self.described_class.table_name.singularize.to_sym
  klass   = self.described_class

  it "maintains a cache key based on the current #{self.described_class.name.downcase} count" do
    klass.cache_key.should == "#{self.described_class.table_name}-0-"
  end

  context "when there are #{self.described_class.table_name} in the database" do
    it "includes the last updated #{self.described_class.name.downcase} in the cache key" do
      e1 = Factory factory
      e2 = Factory factory
      klass.cache_key.should == "#{self.described_class.table_name}-#{self.described_class.count}-#{e2.cache_key}"
    end
  end
end
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
Failure/Error: klass.cache_key.should == "#{self.described_class.table_name}-{self.described_class.count}-#{e2.cache_key}"
   expected: "deliveries-2-deliveries/2-20120315152232"
        got: "deliveries-2-deliveries/1-20120315152232" (using ==)
```

I think the DRY benefits of doing the shared example this way is actually offset by the weird readability of this spec. I'm just trying to make a cache key that works for the entire class the way Rails instance cache keys work. If you can't answer my question but also know a better way to do this then I'd appreciate a recommendation there also.

Thanks!